# Synchronize my app through wifi

Tags: ios5

I'm making an application for meeting rooms reservation, but I want to know if is possible to synchronize my calendar with others ipads in the same wifi with the app installed.

For example I create an event for today at 4:00pm, 
How can my other coworkers can recibe this event in the app calendar. Is this possible with out using and server to synchronize my calendar add between all the ipads in the same wifi?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could have some kind of ID mechanism that identifies each of your co-workers. The app could then query the network foreach of the ipads that are registered to receive your updates. In short, you could use the idea of [multicasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast).

But you must make sure, you can uniquely identify the ipads and have the app running in the back-ground to ensure that the multicast message is received. Hope this makes sense.